# Is there any way to make this symbol ↦?

Tags: arrows

I dont know much about packages and I was wondering if there was one that would let me enter this symbol in math mode: ↦.

Comment: That's just `\mapsto`. No packages needed.

Comment: Oh thanks, i googled "latex arrows" and it didnt appear in the list so i thought i needed a package lmao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\mapsto$

$\longmapsto$
\end{document}
```

[image]